# PCB design in class D amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, class-d

in the process of building a class D amplifier I am now stuck at the point in which I have a lot of audible noise and I don't know where this is coming from.

I know there could be a lot of causes but I want to be sure about the pcb design. I read something about ground current loops but I don't understand how to design the pcb in order to minimize this issue.

My pcb is basically divided in 4 areas:

1. Power supply regulators and caps
2. Input signal conditioning (jfets, opamps, ...)
3. The digital part (ADC, PWM) at low power
4. The power stage (mosfet drivers, inductances, ...)

My specific questions are:

1) In order to minimize noise in the Vsupply and Gnd pins, should each of these areas have their own ground plane? Connecting the 4 gnd planes at the supply gnd.

2) If the gnd current loops are caused by gnd plane points at different voltage, would be better to increase the number of gnd connections from the power supply to the pcb (in order to make the gnd voltage more stable)?

Thank you

Comment: Indeed there are a lot of "undocumented tricks" related to switching amplifiers which are "obvious" to those that have experience but less so to the newbies. Some of the tips you could get as an answer to this question might contradict and cannot all be applied forcing you to make a choice and then you would still not know if that would fix the issue. What I would recommend is to look at existing class D amplifiers and see how they are build. Also study the datasheets of class D amplifier ICs as these often contain implementation advice including a PCB layout example.

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: Have one ground plane under all. Implement "local batteries", which requires a genuine low-pass-filter with series inductor (e.g. 100uH in parallel with 1 ohm to dampen) and shunt 100uFarad right to the Gnd plane, Have separate local-batteries for the audio input circuits, for the ADC, and for the PWM power output.